# Postfix SMTP on port 587 errno connection refused only from localhost

Tags: postfix, smtp, localhost

If I connect from a website from the localhost (127.0.0.1) with port 587 and STARTTLS to my smtp-server on mail.example.tld, I get the the error "Connection refused, errno 111". Connections from a server with another IP are working, the problem occurs only with the localhost on the same server.

When I change mail.example.tld to smtp.example.tld it works.
For smtp.example.tld I have the following DNS entry in my example.tld zone

```
smtp IN CNAME mail.example.tld
```

From netstat I get

```
netstat -tlanp | grep 587
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7617/master
tcp        0      0 [IPv4-Address]:587       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7617/master
tcp6       0      0 [IPv6-Address]:587   :::*                    LISTEN      7617/master
tcp6       0      0 ::1:587                 :::*                    LISTEN      7617/master
```

Postfix listen on all addresses. When I try

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect mail.example.tld:587
```

I get the following

```
139770323395008:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:108:
139770323395008:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:109:
connect:errno=111
```

In my main.cf from postfix I have

```
inet_interfaces = IPv4, [IPv6], localhost
```

When I change it to

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

Then it works.

Why are connections from the localhost refused if I specify my IP addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that "mail.example.tld" doesn't resolve the way you think, usually because of local /etc/hosts ovreride.

Did you try connecting with numeric IP addresses only ?

does "host mail.example.tld" resolve to the same IP address than "ping -c1 mail.example.tld" ?

Comment: That was the problem, thanks. I had in my /etc/hosts
`127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   mail.example.tld mail`

I changed it to:

`127.0.0.1    mail.example.tld localhost mail`

Is that right? I have a webserver and mailserver on it.

Comment: i personnaly prefer to either remove the hostname and only use DNS to resolve, or use the same public IP that is in the DNS in /etc/hosts.
PS: don't forget to accept the answer ^^